# Ionic 2 MEAN Application doesn't return updated data on get request

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, mongoose, ionic2

I've been having this weird issue with an application I'm building.  Essentially a function is invoked I want to read in a user's current game statistics -Wins, losses, draws etc - I do this using a service which creates an observable and consumes data from my rest api.  On first call of this method the data read in is the most current up to date version but after this point I update the document for the user in the database and then when I execute the function again it reads in the original document before the update.  However when I check the database the document has in face been updated.

Here is my provider function for consuming the data.

```
  getUser(id) {
      if (this.data) {
          return Promise.resolve(this.data);
      }
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          this.http.get('https://pitchlife-hearts.herokuapp.com/api/users/' + id)
              .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(data => {
                  this.data = data;
                  resolve(this.data);
              });
      });
  }
```

Here is the call I make in my function.

```
play(challenger, opponent) {
       this.userService.getUser(_id).then((data) => {
                this.challenger_account = {
                    _id: data._id,
                    points: data.maroon_points,
                    wins: data.wins,
                    draws: data.draws,
                    losses: data.losses
                };
```

Here is my update call.

```
    this.userService.updateUser(this.challenger_account);
```

Here is my api endpoint call as well although this does work every time I update the data.

```
app.post('/api/users/update', function (req, res) {
    // Update a user
    var options = {};
    User.update({_id : req.body._id }, {
        maroon_points: req.body.points,
        wins: req.body.wins,
        draws: req.body.draws,
        losses: req.body.losses
    }, options,
        function (err, user) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated as this is driving me crazy.

Comment: When are you updating the `this.data` property that the `getUser(id) { ... }` method uses? Because the first time the `getUser(id) {...}` method is executed, `this.data` is null and because of that the http request is made. But after that, the value of `this.data` is always returned, but if you don't update it manually, it'll be always the first value it was set to.

Comment: Thank you, you legend! I didn't realise this was the case but should have as it's blatantly obvious.  Could you post this as the answer so I can credit you :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Been there, done that lol sometimes we just need to let someone else to take a look at the code to find these things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you updating the `this.data` property that the `getUser(id) { ... }` method uses?

Because the first time the `getUser(id) {...}` method is executed, `this.data` is null and because of that the http request is made. But after that, the value of `this.data` is always returned, but if you don't update it manually, it'll be always the first value it was set to.